# How does is_owner works?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So i am trying to add dev only commands me and my devs get confused on doing this as we need the is_owner but i do not know how to implement it any help here?

So currently i have a shutdown bot command for devs when it is needed:

```
@commands.command(pass_context=True)
@checks.isOwner()
async def shutdown(self, ctx):
    """Shuts the bot down"""
    fmt = 'Shutting down, I will miss you {0.author.name}'
    await self.bot.say(fmt.format(ctx.message))
    await self.bot.logout()
    await self.bot.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if that the person using a command is an *owner* or *developer* of the bot, first you will need to set their ID as `owner_id` when you instance the bot:

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!', owner_id = 123345219197488900, intents = intents)
```

In case you are a group of developers and want to set more than one as `owner_ids`:

```
owners = [123345219197488900, 173545269197488974, 253345719197888931]
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!', owner_ids = set(owners), intents = intents)
```

Then you can use a command check to ensure that the user using this command is an owner.

```
@commands.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.is_owner()
async def shutdown(self, ctx):
```

Comment: Pretty sure it's `commands.is_owner()` not `checks.is_owner()`

Comment: My bad, you are right! I corrected it now.