# How To Make Discord.py dev only Commands

Tags: discord.py

How To Make Discord.py dev only Commands

```
def restart_bot():


os.execv(sys.executable, ['python'] + sys.argv)

@Bot.command(name= 'restart')
  async def restart(ctx):
  await ctx.send("Restarting bot...")
  restart_bot()
```

Comment: Bad idea to restart the bot like that

Comment: its example bro

Comment: There is something called: `@commands.is_owner()`

Comment: @Dominik Post that as an answer!

Comment: @Makonede There is no need for that. It could be closed as a dublicate rather than giving an answer that [already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65844706/how-does-is-owner-works) on this site. If a comment solved the problem this is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can do with `@commands.is_owner()`

basically like this:

```python
@Bot.command(name = 'restart')
@commands.is_owner()
  async def restart(ctx):
  await ctx.send("Restarting bot...")
  restart_bot()
```

thank me later :D